# `git rebase -i` shows ansi colour codes in editor

Tags: git, shell, ansi-escape

When I run `git rebase -i`, I got ansi colour codes showing just after regular todo list (any repos, any editors), where do they come from?

- git versions, tried 2.13 and 2.15 and I nuked my user settings to test
- `color.ui` & `color.interactive` are false.
- tried vim, nano, subl and `ed` in git config (`core.editor`), all have this issue

Thank you.

```
pick 5c0cbe059d56e2fe2bac4bf9e3373d5882157f4a commit
[38;5;252m# Rebase b4c6863..5c0cbe0 onto b4c6863 (1 command)[39m
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Comment: What editor is Git using?

Comment: it's vim, I tried nano too, it's the same issue, so I think it's not the editor I'm using @AndrewMarshall

Comment: Try adding `syntax off` in `~/.vimrc`, but it's not a good solution. It seems vim's syntax color doesn't work well.

Comment: @ElpieKay it's not vim, I tried nano and sublime as well, they got the same issue

Comment: Have you configured a custom `rebase.instructionFormat` format? (Perhaps not—you said you nuked your config to test—but it's always worth checking with `git config --list`.)

Comment: @torek thanks for the tip, good to learn this option, it does affect the todo list, but the ansi code line appears after todo list, it's still there :(

Comment: Also worth testing: try a dumb editor like `ed` that does not use the screen. That would pinpoint whether it's a terminal setting, or actually in the rebase instruction file.

Comment: @torek wow interesting idea, I just tried this, appears the line doesn't show ansi code in `ed` (or `ed` just couldn't process it?) does that mean it's the issue with my terminal? I use iterm I tried macOS's terminal as well eariler, it's the same issue. -edited- after `w` and `q` in ed, git complains unrecognized line, so I think the ansi control codes are there, but ed cannot display them.

Comment: The (presumably ESC followed by) [38;5;252m would change some colors when you print them out - on my Mac I get light grey. I guess this means that you're getting `--color=always` output for some reason, when Git should default to `--color=auto`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160409/discussion-between-dongsheng-cai-and-torek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to fix this, this happens because I created a custom `cat` in my `$PATH`, its content is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -f $(which pygmentize) ]] ; then
  # if pygmentize not installed, use raw cat
  /bin/cat $@
else
  # pip install --user Pygments
  # html output: pygmentize -f html -O full,style=vim
  pygmentize -O style=native -f console256 -g $@;
fi
```

basically it uses `pygmentize` for syntax highlight, I guess `git` is using `cat` to produce the rebase todo list, therefore my custom `cat` pollutes git output.

To fix this, simply rename custom `cat` to something else.